# call a function after user click on button in asp . net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project and here I need is to call the "cal" function after the user click on it as per my knowledge cal function called when button created. I tried to use OnClientClick but its not working please guide me

**Here is my button code (cshtml)**

```
 <button id="SS" class="btn btn-theme" type="submit" Onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Addtodeal", "Sponsor", new { hello = cal() })'">Submit</button>
```

**Cal function :**

```
@functions{
    public int cal()
    {
        int bud = 0;
        string bud1 = Request.Form["budg"];
        if (!bud1.IsEmpty())
        {
            bud = int.Parse(bud1);
        }
        return bud;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Razor in MVC or web pages? `OnClientClick` only exist in webforms server controls, also you can switch `cal` method to controller/code behind instead of declaring `@functions`.

Comment: how can I call cal function from controller ?